# Is it possible to push a UITabbarController from a UINavigationController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UITabBarController that is loading a UINavigationController.

When I push a new view controller, is it possible to change the UITabBarController to a new set of tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, why not just re-assign your new UIViewController's array to UITabBarController's viewControllers property? That will do the trick.

```
- (void)addNewControllers {
    NSMutableArray *controllers = [NSMutableArray array];
    UIViewController *c0 = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    [controllers addObject: c0];

    UIViewController *c1 = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    [controllers addObject: c1];

    UIViewController *c2 = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    [controllers addObject: c2];

    [myTabBarController setViewControllers:controllers];
}
```

Read more about the potential side effects [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBarController/viewControllers).

Comment: im not sure if i follow. can you send me a link or provide sample code?

Comment: sure - I edited my response with some code to take a look at.